# SAILS API - problems deleting rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, sails.js

so I am having a weird problem

I have a normal model in my blueprint with some fields

one of the fields is

```
    id: {
        type: 'integer',
        primaryKey: true
    },
```

so If I create a record (POST) with the id set (let's say id:1) obviously works...
and if I am DELETE-ing the record simply by sending it to

`http://localhost:1337/mymodel/1`

it works just fine... record gets deleted

but if I create a record without specifying the id implicitly, the unique id gets created for me, something like

```
"id": "575ae36015b1122c04ac1159"
```

which doesn't look like an integer, but anyways

if I try to do the same as before

I get an error saying

> No record found with the specified `id`.

I tried changing the id's type to string to see if anything would change, but still not working

I also tried to delete it in the way to send DELETE with JSON body
like

```
{
"id": "575ae36015b1122c04ac1159"
}
```

(and tried even withut quotes)

but still doesn't work...

so whenever the id gets created automatically, DELETE doesn't work

(To be honest, neither does GET.. like this `http://localhost:1337/mymodel/575ae36015b1122c04ac1159`)

So what is particular with autogenerated IDs?

Comment: Well, that clearly isn't an integer. Are you sure it's being saved in the database?

Comment: yes, definitely. It's mongoDB, and gets auto-assigned by mongo!

Comment: Most likely the integer is the wrong type there... coz if I remove the id attribute completely it works OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, there is no need to have the id attribute set, and type integer was definitely wrong.

So after removing the id attribute, all works fine!